# Replace pandas column special characters

Tags: pandas, replace

I have a pandas colum which has special characters such as {{,}},[,],,. (commas are separators).

I tried using the following to replace the special characters with an underscore ('_'), but it is not working. Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [["facebook_{{campaign.name}}"], ["google_[email]"]]
 
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Marketing'])

print(df)

df['Marketing'].str.replace(r"\(|\)|\{|\}|\[|\]|\|", "_")
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                    Marketing
0  facebook_{{campaign.name}}
1              google_[email]
                    Marketing
0  facebook_{{campaign.name}}
1              google_[email]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this `DataFrame` :

```py
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> data = [["facebook_{{campaign.name}}"], ["google_[email]"]]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Marketing'])
>>> df
    Marketing
0   facebook_{{campaign.name}}
1   google_[email]
```

We can use `replace` as you suggested with a `regex`, including `|` which is a `or` operator except for the final `\|` which is the symbol `|`.
Then we deduplicate the double `_` and we remove the final remaining `_` to get the expected result :

```py
>>> df['Marketing'] = df['Marketing'].str.replace(r"\(+|\)+|\{+|\}+|\[+|\]+|\|+|\_+|\.+", "_", regex=True).str.replace(r"_+", "_", regex=True).str.replace(r"_$", "", regex=True)
>>> df
0    facebook_campaign_name
1              google_email
Name: Marketing, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Please see my above edited post, I have added a reproducible code. The string is exactly similar to what I have and it is not working with the solution you have mentioned. Can you kindly comment what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The answer has been updated with your example. Is it the output you expected ?

Comment: I have posted my response below with output. Still no change when I use your code. Not sure why my system is different from your output.

Comment: Ok I see where the problem was. I updated my answer, now I assign the result to the dataframe, I invite you to try this new version. Copy this exact line : 
`df['Marketing'] = df['Marketing'].str.replace(r"\(+|\)+|\{+|\}+|\[+|\]+|\|+|\_+|\.+", "_", regex=True).str.replace(r"_+", "_", regex=True).str.replace(r"_$", "", regex=True)`